# How to send an email from command line?

Tags: email, development, command-line, script

How to send an email from command line or script? I want to be able to run the script programmatically by passing the receiver and the message.

Comment: If you are writing a program many languages have libraries that deal with email

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`mail -s subject someone@example.com` 
type your message, press `Ctrl+D` to finish

Comment: If you haven't configured your system to tell it where to send email, that will probably not actually send email, it will just pile up on my Mac.

Comment: -1: This answer is incomplete. Unless system was configured prior to executing this command, as @TJLuoma noted, this command will not work.

Comment: TJ Luoma and melvkim are incorrect:  a standard OS X system out of the box will send email just fine with no configuration needed.  The OS X machine will act as its own SMTP server, looking up the DNS MX for the destination domain and sending the mail there.

Comment: @JohnEDee At least as you don't expect the receiver to answer to a mail coming from `username@users_mac.local`...

Comment: @patrix, Correct, it uses the logged-in account's long username and the Mac's self-generated ".local" address to form a "From".  I use it all the time for notification emails to me and my staff from shell-scripted processes.  TJ Luoma and melvkim were saying it "will not work" and "not actually send email", however, both of which are incorrect.

Comment: this worked for me.  i got an email in gmail (web) spam folder from <myusername>@<mycomputername>.localdomain

Comment: ah was in spam for me too

Comment: Is there a way I can make this work without pressing the Ctrl+D button? I want to automate emails, so it should work with manual intervention.

Comment: @RamarajT, yes you can pipe the output of the echo command to mail, and it will then not require a Cmd-D.  For example:  `echo This will be the body of the email | mail -s "This is the Subject" destination@example.com`

Comment: Trying this in 2020, nothing arrives, neither in spam, junk nor elsewhere.

Comment: This works in Big Sur on an M1. Zero config.

Comment: Some ISPs block retail customer port 25 connections to control spam.  Depending on your upstream network this method may work great or may not work at all.  That's probably why the comments here are so varied.  If your ISP blocks port 25 you'll need to configure an email gateway/smarthost on your Mac.

Answer (score 29):

There are two programs that I am aware of which will easily allow you to configure your Mac to send email from the command line.

I have written up HOWTOs for both of them:

- [mailsend](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/03/use-mailsend-to-send-email-from-the-terminal/)
- [msmtp](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/04/msmtp-a-free-tool-to-send-email-from-terminal/)

Of the two, I suggest `msmtp`.

Configuration is complicated enough that I'm not sure if I should replicate all of the steps here, but I will mention that if you use
[Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)
you can install msmtp using

`brew install msmtp --with-macosx-keyring`

Then the rest is just a matter of setting up the related configuration files

The first is `/usr/local/etc/msmtprc`

```
# Begin msmtprc
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
tls on
logfile ~/.msmtp.log

# A first gmail address
account example@gmail.com
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
protocol smtp
auth on
from example@gmail.com
user example@gmail.com
tls on
tls_starttls on

# this next line is crucial: you have to point to the correct security certificate for GMail.
# If this doesn't work, check the mstmp documentation
# at http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/documentation.html for help
#
# This next line should all be on one long line:
tls_trust_file /path/to/Thawte Roots/Thawte SSLWeb Server Roots/thawte Premium Server CA/Thawte Premium Server CA.pem

# Set a default account
# You need to set a default account for Mail
account default : example@gmail.com

# end msmtprc
```

Note that `tls_trust_file` line should point to wherever you have downloaded and installed the certificates from https://www.thawte.com/roots/index.html.

I put mine in `~/Dropbox/Thawte Roots` so that I can have it on all of my Macs.

Then you need a `~/.mailrc` file to say where the msmtp binary is located. If you use `brew` it will be `/usr/local/bin/msmtp` so the file would look like this:

```
set sendmail="/usr/local/bin/msmtp"
```

The last but crucial step is making sure your Keychain has the information exactly in the format that msmtp will expect it:

[image]

I think that covers most of the details. See http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/04/msmtp-a-free-tool-to-send-email-from-terminal/ if you want a few more specifics.

Comment: Obviously my examples in the above script assume that you are using Gmail, but it can be used for other servers as well. Change `example@gmail.com` to your Gmail or Google Apps email address.

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work by using the Google Roots available here: https://pki.google.com/roots.pem.  If you are stuck on issues with the trust file and Gmail, this may unblock you.

Comment: If you are having issues with the location of the config (msmtprc) file, after installing with Homebrew on macOS 10.13.3, msmtp looked for it in my home directory:  `~/.msmtprc`

Answer (score 18):

The most basic way to send mail is trough a telnet session with the smtp server of your provider/network. After you contacted the server and after every command the server will answer if it accepts the command with something like "250 OK", or if not with an error message.

All details can be found in RFC2821 - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, Google for it.
This basic way is great for testing why something goes wrong sending mail, but I think it's quite complicated to script it full proof.

First get an command-line interface on your computer, by starting Terminal. Then continue with the following commands, one after one.

Open a telnet session to port 25 of the smtp server of your provider/network

```
telnet name_or_ip_of_smtp_server 25
```

say hello plus the internetname of your provider/network, like abc.com

```
EHLO name_of_your_network
```

a from=return address is needed, the < and > are part of the command

```
MAIL FROM:<your_email_adress>
```

give one or more destinations, the < and > are part of the command

```
RCPT TO:<destination_email_address>
RCPT TO:<second_destination_email_address>
RCPT TO:<etc_destination_email_address>
```

tell the server you want start sending data

```
DATA
```

now the server should answer you can start sending your mail and goes into data-mode

```
your data
more data
etc
```

now finish data with a dot as only char on a line

```
.
```

the server goes back to command-mode so you can quit

```
QUIT
```

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me, it was written with Lion in mind but works for Mountain Lion. Btw this is using Gmail so if you're not...

***You don't need to download anything! (just setup a gmail account)***

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/09/using-macosx-lion-command-line-mail-with-gmail-as-smtp/

Configure Postfix for Gmail SMTP Edit file /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and add in the following below the commented out relayhosts :-

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

Generate sasl_password if not already exists

```
sudo vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

and enter in the following:-

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 username@gmail.com:password
```

Run the following commands

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo launchctl stop org.postfix.master
sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

And you are done….
Now, you should be able to send emails from within the command line e.g. to send the contents of a directory as a tree to an email address

```
tree /var/www/somefolder | mail -s "contents" your@yourdomain.com
```

Comment: PS: I got this to work great when running this manually from Terminal or in scripts. However at this point I'm stuck with the problem that mails are never sent when launchd launches the script. I guess it's a problem with launchd job setup.

Comment: I got it working. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92406/mail-does-not-work-in-scripts-launched-with-launchd

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding this. Really helped me out. All I really needed was the relayhost entry in main.conf (it's my own SMTP server on my LAN).

Comment: The above may be out of date. I had to do add "smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain" as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451135/197789 to get it to work. Otherwise I got a "generic failure" error.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [postfixconf](https://github.com/roubles/postfixconf) that enables and configures OS X to send emails from the command line (using your input).

It is based on the postfix configuration that are well documented on the web [here](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/09/using-macosx-lion-command-line-mail-with-gmail-as-smtp/), [here](http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-mac-os-x-el-capitan/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/6009971).

Comment: I can confirm that this script works on macOS 10.13.6. I set it up with my fastmail account easily. Now `mail someone@some.host` delivers emails as intended.

Answer (score 0):

mtcmail is another option: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33505/mtcmail-cli.

[Ignore this additional text. Added because: body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 27.]

Answer (score -3):

Since it's Unix based, you can use **sendmail** command.

Comment: -1: sendmail is the SMTP server command