# Using launchd to monitor a running program or process

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

I've written a simple bash script to check whether a program (supplied as its only argument) is running and send an email to a set address in the script if it's not. The script works if run on the command line, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work under launchd as a user agent (~/Library/LaunchAgents) where I try to set it to run every minute. The latest incarnation of the relevant .plist file is (monitoring Dropbox):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>greencollar.Dropbox.checkRun</string>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/greencollar/Documents/code/proc_check.sh</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>proc_check.sh</string>
            <string>Dropbox</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Yes - the bash script is executable and no there are no entries in Console indicating any problems with the .plist file. I have tried making /bin/bash the program, but that doesn't seem to make any difference and reading execvp(3) seems to hint that it wouldn't. I've also tried having everything under `<ProgramArguments>` without any luck as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this seems to me pretty basic and it's very frustrating that I can't get it to work!

----------------------------- 1st Edit ---------------------------

Here is the pared-down basics of the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROC=$1
if ! /usr/bin/pgrep $PROC > /dev/null
then
    /bin/echo "$PROC is not running!" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$PROC down" email@mydomain
fi
```

Not much to go wrong there...

Comment: Have you run with the full path as the first argument in ProgramArguments - also what are the permissions on the script? (the easy way is to use LaunchControl or other  programs  to edit the script)

Comment: Also when you say does not run - how would you know if it runs?

Comment: Without omitting anything, other then to put a suitable placeholder for something that's sensitive,  e.g. the actual _email address_ and _password_, etc., edit you question to include the contents of the `proc_check.sh` shell script.  Because without it, there cannot be a complete troubleshooting process that's done easily or by trying to replicate as exact as possible, where the issue is.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks for the comment on my now deleted previous answer.  It made me test the `.plist` in the question, which I admit I hadn't because I thought I saw a problem with it, and it did trigger (on my system anyway).  So, I do not believe that's where the issue is. My new answer I believe may be spot on for where the issue could be.  Obviously without seeing the contents of the _script_ I can't say for sure, however this is most likely where the issue may be.

Comment: I've tested both the `.plist` and the `proc_check.sh`, using my `$HOME` and rest of your path of course, and this works when called by `launchd`  for me in testing with "Caculator" and  `say $PROC is not running`. I didn't test sending email as my system is not setup to do that.  So you might want to test like I did to see if that works and then if it does the troubleshooting will need to be done on how `mail` might be being handled when triggered by `launchd`. BTW I'm running OS X 10.8.5, what version are you running?

Comment: @Mark I am now running with first arg of <ProgramArguments> as full path. But it was triggering anyway without having done that. I didn't say it didn't run. I said it didn't *work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting this far, it had to be some issue with mail being invoked by launchd, so I searched on that and I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92406/mail-does-not-work-in-scripts-launched-with-launchd) which referenced [this](https://superuser.com/questions/281537/using-launchd-for-short-non-daemon-tasks). It *was* the .plist file in that it did not include the AbandonProcessGroup key which would allow the mail process to live long enough to work. Adding

```
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```

made it work.

I was setting myself up for this in that I was using a .plist generated by a 3rd party app to "save time". Such apps are not always complete or accurate in the .plist files they produce, apparently.

Thanks to @user3439894 & @Mark for their help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as an answer because it's to much for a comment and I believe I know what the issue may be, even without seeing the contents of the `proc_check.sh` *shell script*.

I realized after reading again your question and ensuing comments, after deleting my first answer, the *hint* was the *script* worked from the command line but not when called by `launchd`.

When your User Agent `.plist` file is triggered, the `$PATH` it receives may not contain the paths to some commands/utilities that are being called within the *script*.  The `$PATH` passed to the `proc_check.sh` *shell script* is only:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So, any program that is called in the *script* that is not in the above `$PATH` or includes it's *fully qualified pathname* is not running when called by `launchd`.

To fix this, either use the *fully qualified pathname* for all executables called within the *script*, that are not in the above `$PATH`, or add a `PATH=...` statement after the `shebang`, where `...` is the actual output of, `echo $PATH` in Terminal, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Note: The `$PATH` above is what's outputted by `echo $PATH` on my system and may well be different on yours.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I modified my script down to the barest essentials and put the full paths to all executables but it *still* doesn't work. Here is the script:

`#!/bin/bash
PROC=$1
if ! /usr/bin/pgrep $PROC > /dev/null
then
    /bin/echo "$PROC is not running!" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$PROC down" email@mydomain
fi`

It is definitely the script as an improper edit resulted in console messages every minute. But I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @GAM, Please add your script to your question in a properly formatted  structure, not in a comment.