# How to send email from OS X command line

Tags: email, command-line, macos, homebrew, gmail

Dozens of tutorials followed and nothing works.

`msmtp` doesn't work ("TLS certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate" (cert installed)

`postfix` doesn't work (no way to specify `from` address)

`aws ses` doesn't work (unverified email (that's verified))

`mutt` and `mailx` tried every combination with the above.

Comcast and Gmail services tried with the above...

Assuming a bone clean install of El Capitan with Homebrew. Blue sky, spare no expense (I'll buy a service that actually works at this point.)

I need to send an email from the command line.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/how-to-send-an-email-from-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

[Sendemail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) works great with Gmail and all other SMTP servers I have ever tried:

```
brew update
brew install sendemail
man sendemail
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the edit/link/clarification, @patrick.

I also wanted to clarify that I have always used `sendemail` flawlessly on Debian-based systems, but encountered TLS error after upgrading from OS X Mountain Lion to Mavericks when Mavericks was first released.  I don't recall if I even tried to uninstall/re-install from a "Mavericks bottle", but I believe the problem actually had to do with Google updating their accepted handshake protocols or whatnot around this time.

The fix was easily-found by Googling and involved editing a line in the `sendemail` config to [I believe] remove a reference to SSL and replace it with TLS 1.1 (or something of the sort).

I'm sure `sendemail` itself has been upgraded since then to account for this, because I believe I have used it successfully since then on both OS X Yosemite and El Capitan with Gmail without having to make any weird modifications to the configuration.

It truly is a great program, and I cannot give it enough praises.  If any of you are familiar with `blat` for Windows, `sendemail` is like that, except much more powerful and very easy to use.