# Unable to mail from command-line - public/pickup: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, command-line, email

Attempting to send mails using `mail(1)` from the macOS terminal shell results in the following message and the mail is not sent.

```
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

I have checked for the directory where I think it should be and it's there:

```
root# ls -ld /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
prw--w--w-  1 _postfix  _postdrop  0 Dec 31  2016 /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
```

I've read that Postfix is launched ephemerally to send mail but I don't know how - I have no idea how Postfix is configured on macOS. I know Postfix from Linux but am unfamiliar with macOS.

I'd just like to fix this so my script can send email its output.

Pertinent system details:

```
  System Version: macOS 10.12.6 (16G29) (Sierra)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 16.7.0
```

Comment: Did you apply any configuration for Postfix before using it?

Comment: No. I expected it to "just work" because it is a mac :) And it has "just worked" in the past, but likely before an OS update. I have mails sent it the same way dated 2014 so it worked back then.

Comment: To my rather big surprise I just learned that it indeed "just works" :-)

Comment: My answer might not nail your situation. But, we don’t have an answer that I’ve seen saying you should troubleshoot this in the graphical mail app - connection doctor. Can you validate my assumption that you don’t have mail sending from the GUI at the same time as you get failures from the command line?

Comment: Mails send fine using outlook. I'm going to do some more digging based on your answer and report back...

Comment: Outlook doesn’t count. Apple mail app is what configures the default sendmail on macOS. See my answer @starfry in case you’re still looking to get this going

Answer (score 1):

Sending mail from the command line involves two things.

1. Open the Apple mail app (/Applications/Mail.app only) and make sure your default account can send mail (or be sure you configured internet accounts preference pane to provide Apple mail credentials for sendmail )
2. Send the mail without making any command line or Unix changes.

   - [How to send an email from command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/how-to-send-an-email-from-command-line)

Step 1 is missing and assumed in the linked question / selected answer. Also, if you don’t want to send mail from an account you enter in your mail app, grab a stand alone install of `sendemail` as it’s quite easy to set up with your smtp server of choice:

- [How to send email from OS X command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216338/how-to-send-email-from-os-x-command-line)