# File Folder Monitoring

Tags: folders, file, monitoring

I have a task to create a way of monitoring a folder and files running on a MacOS 10.11 machine.

Basically what I want to accomplish is each time a new file is added to the folder send a notification to a monitoring URL and if after 30 minutes no files are added it will trigger an alert.

I am new to Mac OS programming but I have been tasked with this project and just looking for some suggestions on how to accomplish this

Comment: You didn't add details about the intended scope here. Folder monitoring can be done with Folder Actions and AppleScript/Automator, or with tools like Hazel, questions in this direction are on-topic.

Comment: The intention is we have a folder that has incoming files and we want to know potentially when no new files have been moved to the folder in a specified amount of time.

Comment: What will happen with the alert then, does it need to be shown to the user or does it need to trigger some other processing?

Comment: It would send a notification to https://deadmanssnitch.com/ which would fire an email alert

Comment: Then we would manually investigate why no files have been processsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you intend to build something on your own. Things to look into here are

- `launchd`: Allows programs/scripts to be run based on certain conditions. Of special interest for you is probably the `WatchPaths` parameter which allows to watch a path/directory for changes and triggers a program/script if necessary. There *are* race conditions involved here, but for your case you probably can catch them easily. The full format for launchd configuration files is available with `man launchd.plist`
- Shell/bash scripting: The code to execute if a file arrives probably isn't too complex, so some basic scripts should be enough
- [How to send an email from command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/how-to-send-an-email-from-command-line)

---

On second thought, I would ignore the `WatchPaths` part completely. Just use `launchd` to run a shell script every 30 minutes (or whatever is appropriate) which, if no new file has arrived since when-ever, sends a notification to wherever.